# Send Push Notification via Shared Server

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I have bought a SSL in godaddy, I am hosting on shared server. Is that enough for sending push notification?

In the following [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1), it says I should have virtual private server (VPS).

> Push notifications are always sent by a server. For development you
>   can use your Mac as the server (which you’ll do in this tutorial) but
>   for production use, you need at least something like a VPS (Virtual
>   Private Server). A cheap shared hosting account is not good enough.
>   You need to be able to run a background process on the server, install
>   an SSL certificate, and be able to make outgoing TLS connections on
>   certain ports.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, thats enough, but make sure that your Shared Server has the port 2195 open.

Thats a great tutorial. It helps me to do that in a Shared Server.

The way to check if the port is open:

`telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195`